# `You have an error in your SQL syntax;` when using * in query

Tags: mysql

I have query and it works

```sql
select *, id, from_unixtime(start_timestamp) from log limit 1;
```

This also works fine:

```sql
select * from log limit 1;
```

Why I get error if move `*` to the end?

```sql
select id, from_unixtime(start_timestamp), * from log limit 1;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from log limit 1' at line 1
```

Comment: If an asterisk is included into the output list then it must be the most first part of the output list. You put some expression before which causes an error. Add table qualifier: ```select id, from_unixtime(start_timestamp), log.* from log limit 1;```

Comment: @Akina: What is the reason for such limitation? I am from Postgresql world and it allows that.

Comment: MYSQL is just different in so many ways..

Comment: *What is the reason for such limitation?* I think the reason is syntax ambiguity. Possible confuse between an asterisk as "all columns" and as multiplying operator, for example, or when USING/NATURAL joining type is used. The RM does not explain the reason. It can be like compulsory space after `--` in the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that they implemented a short-cut in the SQL parser.

The SQL-2003 specification shows the grammar rules for SELECT as follows:

```
<query specification> ::=
    SELECT [ <set quantifier> ] <select list> <table expression>

<select list> ::=
    <asterisk>
  | <select sublist> [ { <comma> <select sublist> }... ]

<select sublist> ::=
    <derived column>
  | <qualified asterisk>
```

That shows that `SELECT *` is mutually exclusive with a list of comma-separated columns or qualified asterisk. If you use an unqualified `*` then that must be the whole select-list. To implement this grammar, they need both a `<select list>` rule and a `<select sublist>` rule.

But MySQL's [SQL parser Yacc file](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_yacc.yy) shows:

```
query_specification:
      SELECT_SYM
      select_options
      select_item_list
      ...

select_item_list:
      select_item_list ',' select_item
    | select_item
    | '*'
```

They've basically merged the rules for `<select list>` and `<select sublist>` into one recursive rule. So their rule for `select_item_list` allows `SELECT *, <select_item>, <select_item>, ...` whereas by the SQL-2003 standard, it should not allow that.

As a consequence of this short-cut in their grammar, they do not allow the `*` wildcard to be the trailing item in the `select_item_list`.

If MySQL were to "fix" this issue now, to make it comply with the standard syntax rules, it would undoubtedly break thousands of legacy apps that depend on the nonstandard syntax.

You can make your code comply with the standard syntax by avoiding `SELECT *, ...` syntax. Only use `SELECT * FROM ...`. You may also legally use qualified asterisk, like `SELECT t1.*, ...`.